# Freeze Navbar at top of page

Tags: freeze, navbar

I was wondering what you do to make the nav bar freeze at the top of the page. What I mean is that if the nav bar starts about halfway down the page, when a user scrolls down and the nav bar reaches the top I want it to stop there and so that it is always visible. I have seen this on multiple sites, but I am not sure how it is done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With CSS you can set it's position to fixed

```
#navBar{
position:fixed;
height:30px;
...
...
...
}
```